# Why can I run a query in phpmyadmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have written a script that goes like this:

```
<?php
$admin = new stdClass();
$admin->name = "admin";
$admin->passwd = hash("sha256", "*********");
$admin->email = "you@yourdomain.com";

$script = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` 
    ( 
        `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
        `username` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
        `passwd` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        `email` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
        `user_level` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

    INSERT IGNORE INTO `users` (`username`, `passwd`, `email`, `user_level`) 
    VALUES ('{$admin->name}', '{$admin->passwd}', '{$admin->email}', 'admin');
    ";
print_r( $script );
print ("<br /><br /><br />");
$connect->multi_query($script) ? print "tr" : print "fa";
?>
```

And when I run it in phpmyadmin, executes perfectly, but when run from my browser, it doesn't work at all, what could be wrong here?

**The query**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` 
    ( 
        `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
        `username` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
        `passwd` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        `email` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
        `user_level` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

    INSERT IGNORE INTO `users` (`username`, `passwd`, `email`, `user_level`) 
    VALUES ('admin', 'password from hash', 'you@yourdomain.com', 'admin');
```

**`$connect` declaration**

```
$connect = new connect("localhost", "********", "********", "********");
```

**Declaration of `connect` class**

```
<?php

class connect extends mysqli
{
    public function __construct($host = null, $username = null, $passwd = null, $dbname = null)
    {
        $host       = $host     == null ? ini_get("mysqli.default_host")    : $host;
        $username   = $username == null ? ini_get("mysqli.default_user")    : $username;
        $passwd     = $passwd   == null ? ini_get("mysqli.default_pw")      : $passwd;
        $dbname     = $dbname   == null ? ""                                : $dbname;
        return $this->real_connect($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Pat4561, no, I have not got any errors from this

Comment: @Pat4561, even splitting the query (removing the insert) did not work

Comment: Where is `$connect` defined?

Comment: @harris, It is declared in the config.php file

Comment: Is the user you are using allowed to create tables?

Comment: @harris, using `var_dump` on `$connect` shows that it contains the mysqli object instance

Comment: @JasonK, the user I am using has access to everything on the server

Comment: I have added the `$connect` declaration and the `connect` class itself

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your script. Your connect class is the likely culprit. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and see if you get any errors.

Comment: @harris, I have added and it did not show any errors to the client, is there somewhere else I should look for these?

Comment: @harris, I don't know how it was doing it, but when I switched to plain mysqli class it worked, same details and whatnot, just didn't work... But now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize you MySQLi object before invoking `mysqli::real_connect`

So adding `parent::init();` to your `connect` classes constructor should fix it.